# Django template using variable in two blocks

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my template code:

```
{% block content %}
    {% get_latest as latest_posts %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}    
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

In the `content block` the `for loop` does works, but in the `sidebar block` I can't use the variable `latest_posts`. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable's scope is limited to the containing `{% block content %}`. You can either repeat the declaration inside `{% block sidebar %}`, or move it up a level so it's outside of `{% block content %}`.

### example

```
{% get_latest as latest_posts %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}    
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

### or

```
{% block content %}
    {% get_latest as latest_posts %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}  
    {% get_latest as latest_posts %}  
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried with your first sollution, but doesn't work in both blocks :( and in your second example, i don't wanna do 2 sql queries, any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `with` statement:

Definition:

> with Caches a complex variable under a simpler name. This is useful
>   when accessing an “expensive” method (e.g., one that hits the
>   database) multiple times.

Wrap your existing block into this with clause and you can safe yourself some queries. also it should solve your problem :-)  Just remove the `{% get_latest as latest_posts %}` line

```
{% with latest_posts=get_latest %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}    
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        <li>
            <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This is good, now i have another problem, my template tag is now `{% get_latest_posts 6 'category' as latest_posts %}`, how can i use this with `with` statement?